# Issue with bundle install using spree from a git clone:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, bundler, spree, gemfile

Error message: Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "spree_core":

```
  *In Gemfile:
    spree_paypal_express (>= 0) ruby depends on
      spree_core (>= 1.0.0) ruby
    spree (= 0.50.2) ruby depends on
      spree_core (0.50.2)*
```

When I do rails --version, I get:

```
git://github.com/shuber/sortable.git (at master) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install`
```

Have tinkered with the .bashrc profile as suggested by other StackOverflow posts, 'bundle update' gives the same error message as the first one above.

```
Mac OS X Lion
Rails 3.0.7
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [i686-darwin11.3.0], MBARI 0x6770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2011.03
```

'rvm gem list bundler' returns 1.1.3 and 1.1.3 only, on my working environment with this git clone I have bundler 1.1.3 and 1.0.22.

Thoughts? Not really sure what to do at this point. I tried deleting Gemfile.lock and running bundle install again, but no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you specifying the spree gem in your Gemfile?  The error message seems to say you're specifying one version of 'spree' (possibly =0.50.2), while spree_paypal_express is requiring another version (>= 1.0.0).

I'm not too familiar with bundler, so I can't say for certain.  Maybe posting your Gemfile can help us find more leads for you?

Good luck!

Comment: Yep, I tried to answer my own q earlier but since I have noob rep I couldn't yet :) Issue was when I first started toying with spree on my own I used the latest version (1.x.x or something). This app uses 0.50.2 and the global 'override' of the later version was screwing things up. Since it was a git clone and a pretty lengthy app I knew the issue wasn't in the Gemfile. Just started from scratch and created a new gemset. Working fine but something still doesn't seem right amongst the gemsets, idk.